# How to enable SimpleAuthenticator with datastax cassandra binary

Tags: cassandra

Is there a way to enable the Simple Authenticator (for read-only access) for Datastax Binary?

Answer (score 0):

SimpleAuthenticator has been moved out of the main source tree and into the examples section (because it was insecure). If you want to enable it, you have to build it from source. It is not included in any of the binary releases/packages.